# Secure Boot not failing

Tags: windows-10, uefi, efi, secure-boot

I've got a Windows 10 OS and I need to test out if Secure Boot works or not and the easiest way to test that I thought would be to overwrite/remove the digital signatures from EFI binaries in the Windows directory. However, after removing them/replacing them with my own signature, I find that Windows still boots up and no Secure Boot violation is triggered.

I've tried modifying the following EFI files:

```
bootmgr.efi
bootmgrw.efi
winresume.efi
winload.efi
```

Secure Boot is enabled in the BIOS (confirmed via System Information) but why does Windows still boot up? How can I get it to fail without removing all the factory keys?

Comment: The file that the firmware loads is `bootmgfw.efi`. Everything else comes only after that.

Comment: @DanielB I've tried modifying it's signature but it still works. Is there any way to trigger a Secure Boot violation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was modifying files on the Windows partition (C:\Windows\Boot\EFI) instead of the hidden EFI partition where the boot files (bootmgfw.efi) are actually located. By modifying the boot files on the EFI partition I was able to get Secure Boot to trigger a violation.

To access the EFI partition, run in an elevated command prompt:

```
mountvol S: /S
```

Where S: is an unused drive letter and you should be able to navigate through the mounted EFI partition via the command line (cd /D S:)